# Google Play Install Referrer is Oddly Inconsistent

Tags: android, google-ads-api, install-referrer

Recently I've been attempting to attribute Android app installs to specific Google Ads Campaigns.
To do this, I began by tagging all my Google Ads campaigns with data about the campaign and later retrieving the [installReferrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer) string.

I run the following campaign types: *Display and App*
All campaigns have a `referrer` parameter that gets inserted into url at click time, containing a url-encoded JSON string of the campaign's metadata (name, id, etc.).

Once I pull this data from thousands of devices, I come across several inconsistencies.

1. sometimes the `referrer` string contains a query string: `gclid=SOME_GCLID_HERE`.
2. sometimes the gclid is not encoded, and sometimes it is: `gclid%3DSOME_GCLID_HERE`.
3. sometimes the `referrer` string contains `source` and `medium` attributes only: `utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic`
4. sometimes there is just no `referrer` string at all
5. sometimes I get the actual `referrer` string I expected

I can't seem to find documentation on these fluctuations in behavior. What could explain all of this?

Is there any resource I can use to figure why the GCLID comes with some, but my expected string comes with others?

Also, why are some GCLIDs URL encoded and some are not?